# Delete CRLF in Row ending in CRLF

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have been looking for some python code that will count delimiters in a record but can't seme to find any examples.

I have a pipe delimited text file with double quotes for text qualifier with CRLF defining the end of the row. As always some columns have CRLF in the text which confuses the output format.

> "Start of Record"|""|"SomeText"|"More stuff with CRLF then more text"|"Could even have "CRLF included "|""CRLF

Currently I have the file open in notepad++ and was manually going through using regex
 `(?<!")\r\n` 
to find CRLFs without the preceeding double quote. As I have a few large files to fix I would like to get python to go to the start of the record, count the 5 pipes and delete any CRLF that are in that count but have only a very basic knowledge of python.
I have some basic python code to find and replace some characters but don't think it's good enough to do what is required.

```
replacement = {'","':'"|"'}
lines = [] with open('C:\OriginalRplPipe.txt') as infile:
for line in infile:
    for src, target in replacement.items():
        line = line.replace(src,target)
    lines.append(line)with open('C:\PipeDel.txt', 'w') as outfile:
for line in lines:
    outfile.write(line)
    print ("Finished")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I managed to remove the flaw in my first answer. Below is the new code which should do what you want. It should work independently of the number and position of CRLFs in the fields of your record.

```
from pathlib import Path
import re

regex_lin = rb'(".*?"\|".*?"\|".*?"\|".*?"\|".*?"\|".*?"\r\n)' # split file into lines
reo_lin = re.compile(regex_lin, re.DOTALL)
regex_rec = rb'".*?"'                                          # split line into records
reo_rec = re.compile(regex_rec, re.DOTALL)

in_file = Path('input.txt')
out_file = Path('output.txt')

old_content = in_file.read_bytes()                             # read as binary file although it is a text file!

lines = reo_lin.findall(old_content)
new_content = b''
for line in lines:
    old_records = reo_rec.findall(line)
    new_line= b''
    for record in old_records:
        record = record.replace(b'\r', b'')
        record = record.replace(b'\n', b'')
        new_line = new_line + record + b'|'
    new_content = new_content + new_line + b'\r\n'

out_file.write_bytes(new_content)                              # write as binary file although it is a text file!
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I had a few more columns but could work out the pattern to look for and got it done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code is what you are looking for. Unfortunately there is a flaw which, so far, I cannot overcome: if a CRLF appears between 2 double quotes, but immediately after the first one, it is not removed. Apart from that, the code works for me.

```
from pathlib import Path
import re

regex = rb'(".*?[^"])\r\n(.*?")'
reo = re.compile(regex)

in_file = Path('input.txt')
out_file = Path('output.txt')

old_content = in_file.read_bytes()    # read as binary file although it is a text file!

new_content = reo.sub(rb'\1\2', old_content)

out_file.write_bytes(new_content)    # write as binary file although it is a text file!
```

**But now see my second answer.**